Erro Diretiva TagLib Java EE
Estou estudando JSP e estou com dificuldades para adicionar as taglib no arquivo JSP, quando eu adiciono alguma diretiva no arquivo JSP o Intellij não encontra a uri:
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" %>
erro: Cannot resolve taglib with uri http:// java. sun. com/ jsf/ html
estou usando o maven e já adicionei todas as dependências em varias versões diferentes, tanto do Java, quanto das próprias dependências, usei outras URI na taglib, e já tentei buscar ajuda com IA e mesmo assim nada funciona.
Atuais dependências no pom.xml.
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

estou usando o JAVA 21 com TomCat 10.
estou usando alguma dependência errada? a URI está errada?
